# freading 2-byte-long ints in blocks

Tags: c, arrays, file, io, fread

I am reading a file full of 2-byte-long ints into an array

```
FILE *f = fopen("file.bin", "rb");
int *arr;
int len = 2;
```

This works:

```
// method 1
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
     fread(arr + i, len, 1, f);
```

I want this to work the same way:

```
// method 2
fread(arr, len, numberOfElements, f);
```

The goal is to increase performance.

Comment: Use `int16_t` or `short`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reading a bunch of 2-byte ints, you need to read them into an array of 2-byte ints.  The most straightforward way is to use the standard type `int16_t` from `<stdint.h>`.  You would want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

FILE *f = fopen("file.bin", "rb");
int16_t *arr;
int len = 2;

assert(sizeof(*arr) == len);

arr = malloc(numberOfElements * len);

if(arr == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
    exit(1);
}

int r = fread(arr, len, numberOfElements, f);

if(r != numberOfElements) {
    fprintf(stderr, "incorrect number of items read\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

You'll notice that I have added code to allocate `arr`, check that `malloc` succeeded, check that the type we chose matches `len`, and check that `fread` did in fact read the number of items expected.

Comment: Ok but I actually need the array to have ints (32 bit). Also, I might be reading ints of varying lengths from the file.

Comment: @AsoneTuhid To me this is the fundamental issue with "efficient" binary I/O.  If you want to be able to read in big blocks, your in-memory data structure has to exactly match the external representation.  If you can't make them match (for example, if they have different sizes, as you say), you have no choice but to read -- and possible do some conversions -- on an element-by-element basis.

Comment: @AsoneTuhid Also, although I didn't mention it, I think your "method 1" assumes that all the bytes of `*arr` are 0 before you start reading.  Otherwise, if the ints in `*arr` are, say, 4 bytes while you're only reading in 2 bytes, the other two bytes of each int are going to be garbage.  (Also, as you probably know, there's the issue of byte order.)

Comment: Yes, I dealt with those already, thanks. So there's no sneaky way to read a block into memory and partition it somehow?

Comment: @AsoneTuhid The only thing I know of that comes anywhere close is the `readv` system call, and I don't think it's intended to (or could realistically be used for) something like this.